# How to uninstall Adobe CC apps (multiple apps)

Tags: adobe, uninstallation, creative-cloud

I have multiple apps installed from Adobe CC, with the latest update of Adobe CC (2014) all old applications are still there!?! Example: Adobe Photoshop CC and Adobe Photoshop CC (2014) are installed now. Unfortunaly the adobe programs do not appear in Control Panel > Programs and Features. :-(
How can i uninstall Adobe Photoshop CC? Any tips or trics? Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to call the uninstaller by making a WMIC call...
open your CMD as admin
type:

wmic product get name,version

press enter and check the result
if photoshop appears in there try:

wmic product where name="the name of photoshop you found, just copy/paste it" call uninstall /nointeractive

the /nointeractive just makes it uninstall in silent mode, you can remove it if you want to track the progress

Answer (score 0):

The updated "2014" apps use a new binary so require a new install. Ex: You can open a project made with After Effects CC(2014) using After Effects CC (any file you open in the new 2014 will convert the project file)
Personally, I have had to keep both applications to not mess with older projects.

Edit: All of the adobe programs should show up in the Control Panel, you might make sure you are not filtering them out...

Comment: Thank you for your answer Daniel. But unfortunately I am not filtering any programs... They still don't appear in Control Panel > Programs and Features. What a waste of space!